# Multi-select dropdown saves only the last selected value to the database - Laravel

Tags: laravel, multi-select

I want to save multi-select dropdown selected names with comma separated to the database. With my code it saves only last selected value to the database.

Blade.php

```
<div class="form-group">
  <select name="team[]" id="team" class="selectpicker" multiple>
    @foreach ($tdropdown as $tdrop =>$id) 
      <option value="{{$id}}">{{$tdrop}}</option>   
    @endforeach
  </select>
</div>
```

Controller

```
public function empstore(Request $request){

   $employee = new employee();
   $employee->team = $request->team;

  $tarray = $request->input('team');
      
foreach ($tarray as $key => $n) {
   $employee->team = $tarray[$key];
   $result = DB::table('teams')->where('id', '=', "$employee->team")->value('name');
    // $employee->team = implode(',', $tarray);
   $employee->team = $result;
    //var_dump($result);
   $employee->save();
}
   //die();
 return redirect()->route('employee.index')->with('success','Data Added');
    
}
```

When I `var_dump($result);` it outputs all the selected values as follows.

```
string(2) "Team one" string(2) "Team two"
```

But the **above code saves only last selected value**, it means only "Team two" to the database. Please help me to **save all the selected values to the Database**. Thank you.

Comment: Change `$tarray = $request->input('team');` to `$tarray = $request->team;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$teams = $request->input('team', []);

$employee->team = DB::table('teams')
    ->whereIn('id', $teams) // only find the ids we received
    ->pluck('name') // only get the 'name' column
    ->implode(','); // implode into a comma separated list

$employee->save();
```

Comment: One more thing.
I want to **get the selected old values of multi-select dropdown in the edit.blade.php** The multi-select dropdown code is mentioned in the above question. I tried with many ways by surfing internet, but failed. Thank you for any help.